# What are some recommended steps to diagnosing UI latency issues in macOS?

Tags: macos, mac, troubleshooting, diagnostic

I'm new to macOS and wondering the proper way to troubleshoot what might cause UI latency, such as the Emoji/Symbol tool provided in macOS [Use Emoji and Symbols on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-emoji-and-symbols-on-mac-mchlp1560/mac). This is accessed typically by `ctrl+cmd+space`.

- The keyboard is performing as expected in all other ways.
- Activity monitoring shows user cpu of 3%.
- System cpu is 8-10%
- My fan is pretty busy, but overall the load is low at this time. Possibly due to Docker & VSCode on the machine which seem to hit me with performance issues periodically.

I'm not certain what the proper way to troubleshoot why sometimes I'd have no issues with this popup, and other times like today it might not open, or take 30 seconds before it shows up in a delayed way.

Coming from a Windows background, I'd use something like Process Hacker, explore the specific process, and as a last resort even do a Process Monitor trace against a process.

Not certain where to start on something like the emoji/symbol tool on macOS, so any general guidance on how you might recommend to approach a diagnostic process for this would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your memory pressure like? It could possibly be a paging issue if you don't have a whole lot of RAM to spare.

Comment: @Tetsujin memory pressure at 22%. I have 32GB of ram with at least 12GB free at this time. I'll have to keep an eye on that in the future when the problem occurs again.